# http.sys & response time logging

Tags: .net, windows, http, asp.net-web-api2

We've .NET based self hosting WEB Api service.
As we're self hosted we don't have any requests logging/response time logging sinse it is IIS feature.
So, the question is how to get requests logging/response time when using pure self hosting scenario (http.sys). We cannot implement logging on the .NET level because response time will NOT include GC time.
To have real response time number it has to be logged out of the .NET process, I'm wondering if ETW can be used.

Thanks
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself.
Seems the only way it is possible to log http.sys activities is using Event Tracing Windows (ETW), here are 3 related articles:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2007/01/25/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-2-anatomy-of-an-event/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2007/02/01/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-3-typical-request/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307237(v=vs.85).aspx